# Django and MongoDB without django-norel

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

Im been looking at mongo-engine. From what I can see to allow you to use the ListField, DictField etc field types and to use the Django ORM style of db models (with a MongoDB) you need use django-nonrel/djangotoolbox (??)

Is there anyway to intergrate MongoDB with Django without using Django-norel.
I want to use django ORM, mongodb, listfield, dictfield whilst using my current django version.

Thanks,

Comment: Mongoengine? - http://mongoengine.org/#home

Answer (score 1):

You can use MongoEngine directly with Django; it does not use or require `django-nonrel` classes.

The MongoEngine documentation includes a full section on [Django Support](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/django.html) including Authentication, Custom User Models, Sessions, Storage, and Shortcuts.

Per the MongoEngine to Django [connection instructions](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/django.html#connecting), you need to ignore the standard database settings (unless you also plan to use an ORM in your project), and instead call `connect()` somewhere in the settings module.

You also need to add a dummy database backend to your `settings.py` (if you are not using another database backend):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'
    }
}
```

Comment: So if you use the standard django you can stil use listffields types as field types ?